# Joining Multiple data frame to file.txt python based on time

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe, text

I have dataframe like below

```
       X    Y  Z    Value        Time
0      18   55  1      70        100 
1      18   55  2      67        200
2      18   57  2      75        300
3      18   58  1      35        400
4      19   54  2      70        500

        X    Y  Z    Value       Time
0      17   15  1      40        100  
1      17   60  2      67        200
2      17   57  5      75        300 
3      17   79  1      35        400
4      17   54  2      70        500

       X    Y  Z    Value        Time  # Time in milliseconds 
0      15   35  1      70        100
1      15   55  2      67        200
2      15   91  8      75        300 
3      15   58  1      35        400
4      15   60  2      70        500
```

I want to save it as a text file with this format trying to group each row from different data frame for any particular time instant.

```
X    Y  Z     Value  
18   55  1      70
17   15  1      40
15   35  1      70

Time: 100

X    Y  Z     Value  
18   55  2      67
17   60  2      67
15   55  2      67

Time: 200       # time grows 


....
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `concat` then `groupby` split

```
l=[df1,df2,df3]
for y, x in pd.concat(l).groupby('Time'):
    x.drop('Time',1).to_csv('df'+str(y)+'.csv')
```

Comment: Will check and come back.

Comment: @ Wen the above solution created hundreds of text file in my local folder. I want to write them in one single text file